Lebesgue measurable sets with finite measure are almost dyadically elementary
Define a closed dyadic cube to be a cube ${Q}$ of the form
$\displaystyle  Q = [\frac{i_1}{2^n}, \frac{i_1+1}{2^n}] \times \ldots \times [\frac{i_d}{2^n}, \frac{i_d+1}{2^n}]$
for some integers ${n, i_1,\ldots, i_d}$. To avoid some technical issues we shall restrict attention here to “small” cubes of sidelength at most ${1}$, thus we restrict ${n}$ to the non-negative integers, and we will completely ignore “large” cubes of sidelength greater than one.
It can be shown that every open set ${U \subset {\bf R}^d}$ can be expressed as the countable union of almost disjoint dyadic cubes, by writing $U = \bigcup_{Q \in {\mathcal Q}^*} Q$, where  ${{\mathcal Q}^*}$ denote those cubes contained in $U$ which are maximal with respect to set inclusion.

If ${E \subset {\bf R}^d}$ is Lebesgue measurable with finite measure, for every ${\epsilon > 0}$, there exists an integer ${n}$ and a finite union ${F}$ of closed dyadic cubes of sidelength ${2^{-n}}$ such that ${m^*(E \Delta F) \leq \epsilon}$.

Let $U \supset E$ be an open set of finite measure with $ {m^*(U \backslash E) \leq \varepsilon}$, and express $U$ as a countable union of almost disjoint boxes $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$. Since $m(U) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |B_n| < \infty,\ \exists N > 0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N |B_n| \geq m(U) - \varepsilon$. We let $U_\varepsilon := \bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n$. From
$m(U_\varepsilon \Delta U) \leq \varepsilon,\ m(U \Delta E) \leq \varepsilon,\ \forall \varepsilon > 0$,
we get $m(U_\varepsilon \Delta E) \leq \varepsilon$. So $U_\varepsilon$ is the required elementary set.
Question: In principle, smaller $\varepsilon$ should corresponds to finer "scale" (larger $n$). How does the above construction reflect this dependence? I'm guessing it comes from the requirement $m^*(U \backslash E) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |B_n| - m(E) \leq \varepsilon$.

I think here the choice of $n$ is not essential. If an $n\in\mathbb Z_+$ serves the statement, then any $m>n$ also serves, for each closed dyadic cube with side length $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is also finite union of dyadic cubes with sidelength $\frac{1}{2^m}$ for all $m>n$.

@Asigan: This is true. My understanding is that the requirement  $\sum_n |B_n| - m(E) \leq \varepsilon$ capped the maximum size of dyadic cubes we are allowed to use.

Well, if we talk about the maximum length then I think this is true.

Here's an example where $n$ depends on $\epsilon$.  Form $E$ by taking every other dyadic interval in the following way:
$$E = \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} [ \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}, \frac{2^n-1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} ] .$$
To estimate within $\frac{1}{4}$, only one dyadic interval is needed for $U_{\epsilon}$.  To estimate within $\frac{1}{8}$, two dyadic intervals are needed: $[0,\frac{1}{4}]\cup [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{8}]$.  If there was only one dyadic interval, to get an estimate within $\frac{1}{8}$, then it would need to cover a portion of $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{8}]$ which would immediately make the estimate worse than $\frac{1}{8}$, since it would cover the gap $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]$.  It can be proved that $n$ dyadic intervals are required to get an esimate within $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ and $n+1$ intervals are required to have the estimate strictly less than $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

The general case for ${\bf R}^d$ is not hard to establish either. It is known that Lebesgue measurable sets are almost elementary, and elementary sets, being Jordan measurable, has measure equal to $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-nd} \times \hbox{(number of dyadic cubes of sidelength $2^{-n}$ contained in it)}$ (metric entropy formulation of Jordan measurability). combine these two facts we see that $n$ clearly depends on $\varepsilon$. What I'm curious is how the construction in OP serves to illustrate this dependence.
